# Jinja2 check if value exists in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, flask, jinja2

I am trying to check if a value exists inside a list with dictionaries. I use flask 1.0.2. See example below:

```
person_list_dict = [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@mydomain.com",
        "rol": "admin"
    },
    {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "email": "johnsmith@mydomain.com",
        "rol": "user"
    }
]
```

I found two ways to solve this problem, can you tell me which is better?:

## First option: jinja2 built-in template filter "map"

```
<pre>{% if "admin" in person_list_dict|map(attribute="rol") %}YES{% else %}NOPE{% endif %}</pre>
# return YES (john doe) and NOPE (john smith)
```

## Second option: Flask template filter

Flask code:

```
@app.template_filter("is_in_list_dict")
def is_any(search="", list_dict=None, dict_key=""):
    if any(search in element[dict_key] for element in list_dict):
        return True
    return False
```

Template code:

```
<pre>{% if "admin"|is_in_list_dict(person_list_dict, "rol") %} YES {% else %} NOPE {% endif %}</pre>
# return YES (john doe) and NOPE (john smith)
```

Thanks :-).

Comment: If both options are working, and you just need to determine which is better, then maybe codereview.stackexchange.com might be an option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If possible, I would move this logic to the python part of the script before rendering it in Jinja. Because, as stated in the [Jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates): "Without a doubt you should try to remove as much logic from templates as possible."

`any([person['role'] == 'admin' for person in person_dict_list])` is a lot easier to follow at first glance than the other 2 options.

If that's not an option, I would probably use the first, build in function, because I think it's less prone to errors in edge cases as your own solution, and is about 6x less code.

Comment: I prefer the first options because it is developed by jinja and, as you say, it requires less code. Thanks Joost :-).

Comment: Whenever I try to do this I keep getting the error `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'for'`, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Luke: The above example is meant to run in Python, before passing the list to Jinja. It will not run in Jinja.