# Flaks / Jinja nested if statement

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am stuck on a nested if statement, thinking I am approaching it wrong.  I have a list of about 100 products that I am rendering on my page.  I want to have a nested 'if' statement.  Users will have a toolkit, and if the product is in their toolkit, i want to render "Already Uses", else "Add to toolkit?"

```
{% for product in products|sort(attribute="name") %}
    {{ product.name }}
    {% for products in toolkit %}
        {% if product.name in toolkit %}
            <p>Already Uses<p>
        {% else %}
            <p>Add to toolkit?<p>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

more details on: [jinja2 check if value exists in list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226293/jinja2-check-if-value-exists-in-list-of-dictionaries)

You are spot on and on the right path. It would help to provide the structure (as an example) of the `product` object ...

```
{% for product in products|sort(attribute="name") %}
    {{ product.name }}
    {% if product.name in toolkit %}
      <p>Already Uses<p>
    {% else %}
      <p>Add to toolkit?<p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If `toolkit` is a nested map `map`:

```
{% if product.name in toolkit|map(attribute="<whatever has the value equal with product.name>") %}
  <p>Already Uses<p>
{% else %}
  <p>Add to toolkit?<p>
{% endif %}
```